# Impossible to run Multithreading Python script for OTA

Tags: python, python-2.7, ota

I have a problem in the implementation of "ota_from_target_files" for incremental differential packet generation when the thread can not run the thread python script, the error code is as follows:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
unzipping target target-files...
  running:  unzip -o -q target-files-ubi-v2.zip -d /tmp/targetfiles-gaBS0H
--- target info ---
blocksize                 = (int) 131072
boot_size                 = (int) 10485760
default_system_dev_certificate = (str) build/abcd
extfs_sparse_flags        = (str) -s
fstab                     = (dict) {'/cache': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5ad5a90>, '/boot': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5ad5a50>, '/recovery': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5ad5bd0>, '/data': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5ad5ad0>, '/system': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5ad5c10>}
mkyaffs2_extra_flags      = (str) -c 4096 -s 16
recovery_api_version      = (int) 3
recovery_size             = (int) 10485760
system_size               = (int) 10485760
userdata_size             = (int) 10485760
using device-specific extensions in ../../../../device/qcom/common
unzipping source target-files...
  running:  unzip -o -q target-files-ubi-v1.zip -d /tmp/targetfiles-t8l_gX
--- source info ---
blocksize                 = (int) 131072
boot_size                 = (int) 10485760
default_system_dev_certificate = (str) build/abcd
extfs_sparse_flags        = (str) -s
fstab                     = (dict) {'/cache': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5745950>, '/boot': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5745910>, '/recovery': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5745a90>, '/data': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5745990>, '/system': <common.Partition object at 0x7fe6f5745ad0>}
mkyaffs2_extra_flags      = (str) -c 4096 -s 16
recovery_api_version      = (int) 3
recovery_size             = (int) 10485760
system_size               = (int) 10485760
userdata_size             = (int) 10485760
Loading target...
Loading source...
345 diffs to compute
  running:  bsdiff /tmp/tmpqv4XZ8 /tmp/tmpJQqxPt /tmp/tmp2oZB_e
  running:  bsdiff /tmp/tmp3f187L /tmp/tmpeqocoB /tmp/tmpLz7ehS
  running:  bsdiff /tmp/tmpApMu7G /tmp/tmpHya7vh /tmp/tmpsFN1lR
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
 [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 826, in worker
    d.ComputePatch()
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 786, in ComputePatch
    p = Run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 62, in Run
    return subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 826, in worker
    d.ComputePatch()
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 786, in ComputePatch
    p = Run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 62, in Run
    return subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 826, in worker
    d.ComputePatch()
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 786, in ComputePatch
    p = Run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/data/hanjc/mdm9607-le-1-1_apps_proc/apps_proc/bootable/scripts/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 62, in Run
    return subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

using prebuilt boot.img...
using prebuilt boot.img...
using prebuilt recovery.img...
using prebuilt recovery.img...
Skip assertions
Loading radio filesmap...
Loading radio target...
Loading radio source...
Preparing radio-update files...
boot image unchanged; skipping.
recovery image unchanged; skipping.
Applying radio-update script modifications...
done.
```

Please give me advice or help, thank you very much！

Comment: Read, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example][1] and edit your Question accordingly.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I am using "ota_from_target_files" for incremental differential packet generation, "ota_from_target_files" which is the script that Android has, and I have not modified any of its contents!

Comment: I solved it, because the reason I did not install "bsdiff" ,was just fine on it.